# How do you disable physics force field for multiple objects/meshes?

Tags: physics

I have 500 meshes grouped together and I can't find out which one of them has the force field physics activated, but it's there. I assumed a possible solution would be to select all objects, disable force field physics for the active object, then apply the changes to the rest of them... but, if so, how do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object with the force field has circles around it, so it should be shown, else you could play the simulation with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and see where the force comes from :)